# Unable to output from JSON file - Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js

Trying to fetch JSON data when the div is clicked, but not able to see the output. I am using Backbone Collection to pull json data. Tried to output json data to console and also within another div. The content from json file is also listed below.

```
<div class = "test">Click </div>
<div class = "new_test">  </div>
```

JS

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend();

var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model: myModel,
  url : "myjson.json"

})

var jobs = new myCollection();

var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

  el : 'div',
  events : {

    'click div.test' : 'render'
  },
  initialize : function(){

    jobs.fetch();

  },
  render : function(){

    jobs.each(function(myModel){

      var _comp = myModel.get('company');

      $('div.new_test').html(_comp);

      console.log(_comp)
    })

  }
})
```

Json File :

```
[
 {
    "company": "Ford",
    "Type": "Automobile"
 },
 {
    "company": "Nike",
    "Type": "Sports"
 }
]
```

Comment: Cross-browser thinking, I'm not sure a JSON with a collection (here an array) as root element is fine. Theoretically a JSON should have an object a root element. Do you have control on this JSON and could you try with adding a root object above the collection ?

Comment: @Ricola3D http://www.json.org/ "JSON is built on two structures"

Comment: When you click test, is it fetching the data? And if it is, is the data being returned? Check your console for cross-domain issues. Also you should render on the reset of the collection, because you might click on the div before the data has been returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the render function of your view to see the results. You cannot instantiate a collection object and expect to see results.

**Code hasn't been tested.**

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({


el : 'div',
events : {

    'click div.test' : 'render'
        },
initialize : function(){

    jobs.fetch();
    this.render();

},
render : function(){

    jobs.each(function(myModel){

    var _comp = myModel.get('company');

     $('div.new_test').html(_comp);

    console.log(_comp)
    })

}
})

var yourView = new myView();
```

Comment: `fetch` is asynchronous, he won't see anything with this either. Replace it with `jobs.fetch({success: this.render});` (or such).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem a few weeks ago.

Check  path for Your JSON. 
For example when You have structure of directories like this:

```
   -js
     - collection 
        collection.js
     - json
        myjson.json
```

Backbone collection You set like this:

```
       url: 'js/json/event.json',
```

Check in Firefox, in Chrome we have a Cross-browser thinking
and check this:

```
          jobs.fetch({
                reset: true,
                success: function (model, attributes) {
                   //check here if json is loaded
                }
            });
```